# Cassandra fails when writing (two nodes, RF=1, ANY write consistency level)

Tags: cassandra

I'm wondering why this happens with the parameters N=2, RF=1, and ANY write consistency level. The error I get is:

```
HUnavailableException: May not be enough replicas present to handle consistency level.
```

Should RF be set to 2 instead? If so, why? ANY is meant to "just write it somewhere", isn't it?

(version of Cassandra is 1.2.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Hector.  Cassandra will never reject a write at ANY.  (Unless it's so behind on its workload that it has to refuse new writes temporarily to catch up; in that case it will return OverloadedException, not Unavailable.)

Best practice today is to use the [native Java driver](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/the-native-cql-java-driver-goes-ga) rather than Hector.

Comment: Yes, we've realized recently that there is some bug in Hector with setting the consistency level. Thank you!